# Angular 4 + firebase authentication on iphone 5 no work

Tags: iphone, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have such a problem:
Firebase authentication working in computer, android devices and iphone 4, 6.
But no work on iphone 5. When click enter, nothing happens. 
What can be?
Thank you very much.

component.ts

```
onLogin(){
    let data = {
       email: this.user.email,
       password: this.user.password
    }
    this.af.auth.login(data).catch(function(error){

    });

  }
```

component.html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <md-input-container class="full-width">
          <input mdInput name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <md-input-container class="full-width">
          <input mdInput name="password" type="password" required placeholder="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button md-raised-button type="submit">enter</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you log the error that is getting thrown (provided there is one)? It will be very helpful in debugging the issue.

Comment: how can see errors on mobile phone?                                
window.onerror = function () {
 alert('An error has occurred!');
 return true;
};  no work. Alert no show

Comment: `this.af.auth.login(data).catch(function(error){alert(JSON.stringify(error); });`

Comment: I checked this method, it does not give an error, just nothing happens.
If I'm hanging events on a button before this.af.auth.login (data), event work, only this function not work ->this.af.auth.login (data)